# Find begins and ends of gaps in timeseries

Tags: r, posixct

I need to find gaps in timeseries to highlight them in ggpot2. I need datetime of begin and end of gap and it's length in hours. Here is my code with example data.

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 10000

data <- tibble (
  id=1:n, 
  datetime=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2020-07-15 12:45:00"), by="15 sec", length.out=n),
  Value=sample(0:100, n, replace=TRUE),
  Instance=sample(LETTERS, n, replace = TRUE)
)


data <- data[-c(100:1000),]
data <- data[-c(5000:6000),]


data$timegroup = c(0, cumsum(diff(data$datetime) > 3600))

timegroups <- unique(data$timegroup)

all_empty_dates <- c()

if (length(timegroups) >= 2) {
  
  for (i in 0:(length(timegroups)-2))   {
    
    time_offset <- as.difftime(15, format = "%X", units = "mins")
    
    start <-  last (( data %>% filter (timegroup == i))$datetime) + time_offset
    
    end <- first (( data %>% filter (timegroup == i+1))$datetime) - time_offset
    
    tg_empty_date  <- data.frame (start = start, end = end, length = difftime(  end,  start, units = "hours"))
    
    all_empty_dates <- rbind (all_empty_dates, tg_empty_date)
  }
}

print (all_empty_dates)
```

Here is what I got:

```
                start                 end         length
1 2020-07-15 13:24:30 2020-07-15 16:40:00 3.258333 hours
2 2020-07-16 13:34:45 2020-07-16 17:15:15 3.675000 hours
```

The code is working but I don't like approach I use - finding periods without gaps first instead of finding gaps. I also use For Next which looks weird in R. Is there a better way to reach same result?

Comment: how is gap defined?

Comment: are you sure your sample data is correct. n = 10000, but data has 50000 rows since Instance repeats LETTERS[1:10] 5000 times... So you also get double timestamps, which probably messes up code, since timegroup 2 starts before timegroup 1 has ended..

Comment: Gap is if 3600 seconds between samples. Data sample is fixed now - 10000 rows in dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  #For each timegroup
  group_by(timegroup) %>%
  #select 1st and last row
  slice(1, n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  #Drop 1st and last row of the entire dataset
  slice(-1, -n()) %>%
  #Add 15 minutes to datetime to create start column
  #Subtract 15 minutes to datetime to create end column
  transmute(start = datetime + minutes(15), 
            end = datetime - minutes(15)) %>%
  #Create group of 2 rows
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>%
  #Select first and last value from start and end and 
  #get difference between them in hours
  summarise(start = first(start), 
            end = last(end),
            length = difftime(end, start, 'hours')) %>%
  select(-grp) 

#  start               end                 length        
#  <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>        
#1 2020-07-15 13:24:30 2020-07-15 16:40:00 3.258333 hours
#2 2020-07-16 13:34:45 2020-07-16 17:15:15 3.675000 hours
```